# How to only show animation the first time html css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

The first time you visit my website, I have an animation that says

"Hello. I'm Bob", and that animation slowly fades in. Then through the nav bar, a user can go on another page of the website.

The problem is that if they go **back** to home (the main page), then the animation shows **again**. This time I just want the "Hello. I'm Bob". No animation.

```
$(".fade-in-first").addClass("animated fadeInUp");
setTimeout(function(){
     $(".fade-in-second").animate({ opacity: 1 });
    $(".btn-explore").addClass("pulse-anim");
}, 1300);
```

My jQuery above is the animation. I want something like ... `if (count) == 0, then animate, count ++`

I tried setting a variable and doing it, but it did not work.

Comment: use `localstorage` to track it and you can do that for each *session*...

Comment: how could setting count locally not work , may be you are initializing it again when back button is pressed.

Comment: You can use sessionstorage through javascript now to store a variable in browser itself. When user comes next time to page and variable is there with valid value, don't show modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to store the fact that user has seen the animation.

I'm not sure about the setTimeout you used... But I left it.

```
$(".fade-in-first").addClass("animated fadeInUp");
setTimeout(function(){
  if(typeof(localStorage.getItem("welcomeShown")) != null && localStorage.getItem("welcomeShown") != "true"){
    $(".fade-in-second").animate({ opacity: 1 },5000);
    localStorage.setItem("welcomeShown","true");
  }else{
    $(".fade-in-second").css("opacity",1);
  }

  $(".btn-explore").addClass("pulse-anim");
}, 1300);
```

You can try it in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/wqqYgd), where there also is a button to clear the localStorage (to retry many times!)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that their browser is reloading your site when they return to your homepage (i.e. you're not creating a single-page app), then your scripts will be reinitialized as well. So your `count` won't retain the value it had, which it would need to keep track of the user's prior visit.

In this case, you'll need to either store a cookie, or use either `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`.

```js
// sessionStorage or localStorage (localStorage usage is exactly the same)
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('hasVisited')) {
  $(".fade-in-first").addClass("animated fadeInUp");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".fade-in-second").animate({ opacity: 1 });
    $(".btn-explore").addClass("pulse-anim");
  }, 1300);

  sessionStorage.setItem('hasVisited', true); 
}
```

Use `sessionStorage` if you only want to keep track of their homepage visit for the current session, which is supposed to last as long as the current tab, window, or browser isn't closed. In practice, it seems sessionStorage can last across tab close/reopen, possibly in vendor-specific ways due to how they handle tab history. Also, items in sessionStorage are not shared across tabs, so if your user has the page open in multiple tabs, and returns to the homepage from a different tab than the one they started with, they'll see your animation again.

Use `localStorage` if you want the value to persist across different sessions, and across tabs. All tabs being used to browse your site will have access to the same synchronized localStorage object.

**Note 1:** It's recommended to read and set values from the `Web Storage API` (`session/localStorage`) using `setItem() / getItem()` as above, rather than reading from and writing directly to the object, to avoid dealing with issues of reading values inherited from the prototype, and to avoid overwriting existing properties.

For example, if you do the following:

```js
localStorage.key = 'My key value';
console.log(localStorage.key);
```

you'll notice that the value you set is indeed available and readable, but unfortunately you've now overwritten the `key` method of the localStorage object!

**Note 2:** These values will only be accessible on the same subdomain, through the same protocol! So if you go from `www.example.com` to `login.example.com`, or from `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, the values won't be retained.

### Cookies

As mentioned you can also use cookies, but it's a bit more work to parse the values (though you're already using jQuery, so it wouldn't be too bad). You also have to be mindful of what `path` you're setting for the cookie, otherwise it'll only apply to the path where you set it. There's the value of `expires` to consider as well. See the following links for more info:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more modular solution as you may want to check if they have visited in more than one case.

```
if (!localStorage.isFirstVisit) {
    localStorage.isFirstVisit = true;
} else if (localStorage.isFirstVisit == 'true') {
    localStorage.isFirstVisit = false;
}

if((localStorage.isFirstVisit == 'true') {
    $(".fade-in-first").addClass("animated fadeInUp");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".fade-in-second").animate({ opacity: 1 });
        $(".btn-explore").addClass("pulse-anim");
    }, 1300);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use LocalStorage to set an attribute that the animation on a specific page is loaded, so you don't replay it. I don't like this approach because until the user has not cleared his localstorage, he cannot see the animation anymore...
An approach that in my opinion is better is to set a cookie with an small expiration time, like 1 day.

For example with localStorage:

```
// 1 - using LocalStorage: play anim only one time until the localstorage is cleared:
if (!window.localStorage.getItem('homeAnimPlayed')) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('homeAnimPlayed', "true");
        this.setState({ animationLoaded: true })
    }, 3000);
} else {
    this.setState({ animationLoaded: true })
}
```

using a cookie:

```
// 2 - using a cookie: you can set a custom expiration, for example 1 day. 


// use this 2 function to read/write cookies with a custom expire date
function writeCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

// then you can set the cookie: play anim only one time: expires in 1 days
let cookie = readCookie("animPlayed_home");
if (!cookie) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        writeCookie("animPlayed_home", "true", 1);
        this.setState({ animationLoaded: true })
    }, 3000);
} else {
    this.setState({ animationLoaded: true })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is little value in contributing to a question that has an accepted answer and is 3 years old